# EF core Join two table without primary key column

Tags: join, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //I should join with User.UserName and UserRoles.UserName
    public List<UserRoles> UserRolesList { get; set; }
}

[Table("Role")]
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleKey { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserRoles")]
public class UserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string RoleKey { get; set; }
}



public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRolesList { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}

//Getting all users with roles
     var usersWithRoles= _dbContext.Users.Include(b => b.UserRolesList).ToList();
```

I have 3 tables (User,Role and UserRoles), I want to joins User and UserRoles table with UserName column. But EntityFramework not allow doing this with out primary key column. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design the UserRole table like below

```
[Table("UserRoles")]
public class UserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public User User {get; set;}
    public Role Role {get;set;}
}
```

Using thing you can now join with userId and get the user name from user table. Also can join with role table by roleId and can get role key.

Comment: This code is a sample of my problem to explain it easly.In  UserRoles table, I don't have UserId and RoleId columns,